# openerp - how to change import default values : encode type and separator values

Tags: python, csv, import, odoo

My question is simple, how to propose by default semicolon and Latin encoding instead of the comma and utf8 in the the openErp 6.1 import dialog box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change it. you must edit addons\base_import\static\src\js\import.js and change the Code on line 189/190 to the following:

```
initSelection: function (e, c) {
  return c({id: '\t', text: _t("Tab")});
```

same goes for the encoding. Change accordingly on line 169/170.

Answer (score -3):

First you can select the file which you want to import and then click on Import Options text in import popup so there is multiple option for encoding, separator and delimiter etc... So you can just change the separator and encoding option.

Comment: thx for the answer.
I just want to change the built-in default separator/encoding to facilitate the import of data by applicants who do not know that kind of vocabulary.
Of course I know how to import data from a csv to openerp